# How to sort SPFileCollection in sharepoint?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I guess question says it all ?

Any ideas will be appreciated ;)

Answer (score 5):

What about a little bit of Linq ?

Something like this should work :

```
var sortedFiles = fileCollection.Cast<SPFile>().OrderBy(file => file.Name).ToList();
```

Comment: Can you elaborate here what your're are trying to do? it look really simple though!

Comment: I'm using the built in OrderBy extension on an IEnumerable provided by Linq but since the SPFileCollection doesn't implement IEnumerable, I have first to cast to a collection of SPFile (which can then be used by Linq to apply the sort order).

I didn't have the opportunity to fire visual studio to test it but I see no reason why it shouldn't work.